# Comparing dates in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Why does comparison works weird in this example?
Dates, which are birthdays, are:

```
1990-03-22
1998-03-20
1990-03-22
2002-12-02
2004-03-18
2004-03-20
2004-03-25
```

I'm doing this

```
WHERE DATEADD(YY, 18, jun.birth_date) >= DATEADD(YY, 1, GETDATE())
```

Which, I think, should cut off all the entries of people older than 18 in a year from today. But it does absolutely opposite, here's what I get:

```
2004-03-18
2004-03-20
2004-03-25
```

And I get right results when I seacrh for entries less and even than date in the next year.
Why does it work like this?

Comment: If you want people who are 18 or older today, why are adding a year to `GETDATE`?

Comment: In English this SQL says; where the 18th birthday is a year or more in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your have...

```
WHERE
    someone's date of birth + 18 years
    >=
    Today's date + 1 year
```

In English, thats; `where the 18th birthday is a year or more in the future.`

I think what you really want (if you want people who are 18 or older) is... `WHERE the birthdate is earlier than today's date minus 18 years` *(18 or more years ago)*

```
WHERE
    Jun.birth_date <= DATEADD(YY, -18, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want people who are 18, or older today, then take 18 years off today, don't add years to the DoB column, as that makes the query non-SARGable:

```sql
SELECT birth_date
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE birth_date <= DATEADD(YEAR, -18, CONVERT(date,GETDATE()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `datediff`, instead of `dateadd`?

```
with d as (
  select cast('1990-03-22' as date) as birthDate union all
  select cast('1998-03-20' as date) as birthDate union all
  select cast('1990-03-22' as date) as birthDate union all
  select cast('2002-12-02' as date) as birthDate union all
  select cast('2004-03-18' as date) as birthDate union all
  select cast('2004-03-20' as date) as birthDate union all
  select cast('2004-03-25' as date) as birthDate 
)
select *
from d
where datediff(year,birthDate, getdate()) >= 18
```

It's easier to understand the behaviour.

Comment: *"Why don't you use `datediff`, instead of `dateadd`?"* because it's still not SARGable.

Comment: @Larnu, as far as I see in the question, it's not a concern. If not so, for me is far way easier to understand this query using `datediff` instead of `dateadd`.

Comment: Applying functions to the column being searched is a bad habit. Once taught it's hard to unteach.  I agree this is functionally correct and SLIGHTLY easier to understand, but as far as SQL goes, it's my Opinion that this is still an anti-pattern and as such I agree with Larnu.  `Born on or before 18 years ago` is hardly a hard concept, even if `Age >= 18` IS a trivial concept.

Comment: Hi @MatBailie. I understand why is better to avoid to use functions to the column searched, but I just said that depending on the size of the data, can be a problem or not. And if the query is easier to understand, maybe is justified to pay it, bearing in mind that the cost can be zero.

Comment: In addition, the `datediff` won't return a year until it's reached, so it's not true that the `Age >= 18` is trivial. For example `select datediff(year,'2020-01-01', '2021-01-01')` returns 1, but `select datediff(year,'2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')` returns 0.

Comment: To cite a reference for @JaimeDrq: From [`datediff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value): "The `int` difference between the _startdate_ and _enddate_, expressed in the boundary set by _datepart_." In this case the _boundary_ is the change of a year, e.g. 2020-12-31 and 2021-01-01 are separated by one year. 2020-01-01 and 2021-12-31 are also separated by one year.